# How to implemnent Paging with kendo pager on demand web api call

Tags: kendo-ui

Am calling web api method from view model and getting the 10 records per click. I want paging for kendo template.

this is my code:

// this is the web api method which gets 10 records per each call

```
   function WebApiMethod(parameter)
    {

        var url = webApiUrl + 'api/{controller}/{methodname}';
        var success = function(result)
        {
        }
        CallWebApi(url, 'POST', success, parameter);
    }
```

///this is the ajax call that am calling from webapimethod

```
function CallWebApi(url, type, successCallBack, data) {

    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({    
        cache: false,
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: successCallBack,

        error: function (xhr, err) {

        }
    });
}
```

///this is the kendo pager in which am biding the datasource

```
function KendoPager()
{

        var pager = $("#pager").kendoPager({
            dataSource: ViewModels["NameOfVM"].dataSource,
            info: false,
            change: function () {
                ViewModels["NameOfVM"].pageIndex = pager.page();
            }
        }).data("kendoPager");
    }
```

//this is the datasource am bind to kendopager

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging:true,
    pageSize:10,
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show some code that where we can show how to do it?

Comment: can you please look into the code ....

Comment: @OnaBai: can you plaese help me out....

Comment: I cannot see any reference to templates. How are you planning to use the template? Any idea? Any progress so far?

Comment: yeah am facing problem with pager, i didn't psoted the template code. Am trying to get the pager for that binded datasource working on it. In articles it is like use transport->read->url property i used that for hitting the web api method in controller but is not hitting the method.

Comment: I used the above webapimethod ajax call by that onload getting the result of 10 records in this case kendopager showing 1 buttonCount in pager but unable to get the paging for total records no progress on that.